# python - possible to use multiple fields on a re.split

Tags: python-2.7

This should be a quick one,

I'm doing a `re.split` and want to use multiple results from this on the same line.

Y«To simplify it, see below:

```
import re
string = "Hello world my name is richard"
print (re.split('\s+', string)[1])
```

now instead of just using result "1" I want to use 1 and 3 so "world name"

is this possible ?

Comment: Why do you need regex for this?

Comment: `x = re.split('\s+', string); print( x[1] + " " + x[3] )`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter()`, no need for a regex here:

```
from operator import itemgetter

string = "Hello world my name is richard"

' '.join(itemgetter(*[1,3])(string.split()))
```

Returns:

```
world name
```